# "That's as much as we ever really saw of them at the time". What does this sentence mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Below is a paragraph from my English textbook:

> Bob – both my parents were in the theatre and they had made quite a
>   name for themselves on the stage. As a child I remember our house
>   being constantly full of famous people, laughing and talking. My
>   sisters and me would be brought down by our nanny to kiss parents
>   goodnight and then we would be packed off to the nursery. **That's as
>   much as we ever really saw of them at the time**. It's better now,
>   but it has left a mark on all of us – we ring each other now and
>   again, but that's about all. I think my father understands this, but I
>   am not sure my mother does.
>   Source: http://sinhngu.com/f_view.asp?CID=1908&QID=17677

I'm quite confused about the meaning of the bold sentence. I guess its meaning may be:

(1) That's the most we at any time (during our childhood) really met our parents when we were children.

or I can explain it in another longer way:

(2) During our childhood, we rarely met our parents except when our nanny brought us down to kiss our parents goodnight.

Could you please tell me whether or not I have understood that sentence correctly?

Comment: 2) is quite a good match.

Answer (score 1):

That's as much as we really ever saw of them at the time.

Breaking down the meaning of much:

1) **how much**: **How much do you see them**? I don't see them much at all.

**How much** here means **How often** or **How frequently**.

2) **How much do you see them?** can also be expressed as: **How much do you see of them**?.

Possible answers are: I see them a lot; I don't see them a lot; I don't see them much. I don't see much of them. I don't see a lot of them.

3) Here the amount of time or frequency of these kids seeing their parents is **limited to the parties** where he would kiss them goodnight.

In descriptions in English, we refer back to what we have already said using: That's. That's=the occasion of the parties when they kissed them goodnight.

4) This **much** and **much of** can be used as a comparative adverb as in:  He drove **as slowly as** I drove. I didn't see them **as much as** I would have liked. I didn't see as **much of them** as I would have liked.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Could you please also explain the word 'ever' in that case? Does 'ever' in that sentence mean 'at any time (during our childhood)'?

Comment: I'm still confused about your (4) explanation. I think your examples mean 'He and I drove slowly. We drove at the same speed' and 'I didn't see them as frequently as I expected / wanted'. Then, I'm not sure if I understand the orgininal sentence correctly: the number of parties when children kissed parents goodnight is the maximal number of times that the children saw their parents during their childhood